# For what types of objects is the outer product defined in geometric algebra?

Tags: geometric-algebras, outer-product

I just started to learn geometric algebra from the "Geometric Algebra for Physicists" book. Authors first give definition of outer product of two vectors $a \wedge b$. Then they give geometric product in terms of inner and outer product: $ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$, but then they define the outer product through the geometric product: $a \wedge b = \frac{1}{2}(ab - ba)$.

As I understand, geometric product is defined for all elements in the algebra, so is outer product defined for all of them too?

For example, given $\mathcal{G}2$ algebra where elements are $a = a_0 + a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_1 e_2$, what does the outer product of vector with bivector would mean? $a \wedge b = (a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2) \wedge (b_3 e_1 e_2) = a_1 b_3 (e_1 \wedge (e_1 e_2)) + a_2 b_3 (e_2 \wedge (e_1 e_2))$ what do I do next?

Can I compute outer product of vector with the scalar? Like, $a_0 \wedge (b_1 e_1 + b_2 e_2)$. If it is defined, what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $ab = a\cdot b + a\wedge b$ is neither a definition of the geometric product nor even valid in general. When it is first introduced in Doran and Lasenby's *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be vectors. Similarly, the equation
$$
  a\wedge b = \frac12(ab - ba)
$$
is valid for vectors but is not valid in general. It is also not stated that this is a definition of the exterior product of vectors, merely that it *can be* if the geometric product is already defined.

You should consider reading Chapter 4 "Foundations of Geometric Algebra" if you have not already.

---

One way to define the exterior product is via grade projections of the geometric product.

If $A_r$ is an $r$-vector and $B_s$ is an $s$-vector then
$$
  A_r\wedge B_s := \langle A_rB_s\rangle_{r+s}
$$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle_{r+s}$ is the $(r+s)$-vector component (and is of course zero if there is no such component). Because every multivector is a sum of homogeneous multivectors, we simply extend this definition by linearity: if $n$ is the dimension of our base vector space and
$$
  A = \sum_{i=0}^nA_i,\quad B = \sum_{i=0}^nB_i
$$
where $A_i, B_i$ are $i$-vectors, then
$$
  A\wedge B := \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\langle A_iB_j\rangle_{i+j}.
$$

For your example, this looks like
$$\begin{aligned}
  &(a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2) \wedge (b_3 e_1 e_2)
\\
  &= a_1 b_3 e_1 \wedge (e_1 e_2) + a_2 b_3 e_2 \wedge (e_1 e_2)
\\
  &= a_1b_3\langle e_1e_1e_2\rangle_3 + a_2b_3\langle e_2e_1e_2\rangle_3
\end{aligned}$$
then
$$
  \langle e_1e_1e_2\rangle_3 = e_1^2\langle e_2\rangle_3 = 0,
$$$$
  \langle e_2e_1e_2\rangle_3 = -e_2^2\langle e_1\rangle_3 = 0
$$
so the whole expression is $0$. I've used the fact that $e_i^2$ is a scalar and that $e_ie_j = -e_je_i$ when $i\ne j$.

---

Practically, what might help the most are the following facts:

1. The exterior product is associative and bilinear.
2. If $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ are vectors then
   $$
     V := v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k =  0 \iff \text{those vectors are linearly dependent}
   $$
   and $V$ is always a $k$-vector (in fact, a $k$-blade). It follows that when $V \ne 0$ and $u$ is a vector then
   $$
     u\wedge V = 0 \iff u \in \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}.
   $$

In fact, these properties *completely characterize* the exterior product. We can derive two more key facts:

3. If $v, w$ are vectors then $v\wedge v = 0$ and equivalently $v\wedge w = -w\wedge v$.
4. Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_s$ be linearly independent vectors and $w_1,\dotsc,w_r$ also be linearly independent vectors. Then there is a scalar $a$ such that
   $$
     v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_r = aw_1\wedge\dotsb w_s
   $$
   if and only if
   $$
     \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_r\} = \mathrm{span}\{w_1,\dotsc,w_s\}.
   $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for such thorough answer! There's a lot to unpack, and I'm definitely going to read the book you suggested.

Just a couple more questions though:
1. I see when you defined 
$A\wedge B := \sum_{i=1}^n...$ 
the sums start from 1. Does that mean that we cannot do exterior product with the scalar as in the second example in the question, or we can, but it would be equal to 0?

Comment: 2. I do not understand what does subscript "3" in $\langle e_1 \rangle_3$ mean? Inside of it only $e_1$ which means it's $\langle ... \rangle_1$ isn't it?
I definitely need to read that book, because maybe I just do not understand notation and meaning behind it.
3. If we're dealing with $\mathcal{G}_n$ can we automatically say any $\langle ... \rangle_k = 0$ for $k > n$ ?

Comment: @ViacheslavRadko The book I "suggested" is the one you're already reading, I just referred you to a later chapter. (1) Good catch on the summation, it should start from zero, I will edit. (2) The subscript is the grade we're projecting onto. So for instance $$X = 1 + 5e_1 + e_2e_2e_3 + 3e_1e_2 - 2e_2e_3,$$$$\langle X\rangle_0 = 1,\quad \langle X\rangle_1 = 5e_1 + e_2^2e_3,\quad \langle X\rangle_2=3e_1e_2-2e_2e_3.$$ Note how $e_2^2$ is a scalar. So it is exactly because $e_1$ is just a vector that $\langle e_1\rangle_3=0$. Your observation that $\langle\cdots\rangle_k = 0$ for $k>n$ is correct.

Comment: @ViacheslavRadko I should note explicitly, the exterior product with a scalar is just scalar multiplication, i.e. for any multivector $X$ and scalar $a$ we have $$a\wedge X = aX,$$ and this follows directly from the definition I gave above.

Comment: Oh, I thought "Foundation of Geometric Algebra" is the name of the book, because I didn't read the 4th chapter yet.

Thank you so much! Everything is clear now!